# Python - How do you remove characters recieved as a list from an ldap query?

Tags: python, split, ldap

I have performed an LDAP query looking for a list of Windows Servers, the result returned is a list. I used the filter of CN and the below is a sample from the response, I have 1000's in the raw file.

```
('CN=SERVER1,OU=General Servers,OU=Servers,OU=Computers,OU=Group,DC=Domain,DC=com', {}),
('CN=SERVER2,OU=General Servers,OU=Servers,OU=Computers,OU=Group,DC=Domain,DC=com', {})
```

I only need the name, in this sample that would be 'SERVER1' or 'SERVER2'

What is the best way to split this list, removing 'CN=' and everything after and including the ','

If someone is aware of a better ldap query than

```
(r"(&(objectclass=computer)(objectcategory=computer)(operatingSystem=Windows*Server*)(cn=*))")
```

Using a different filter than,CN or sAMAccountName that returns just the host names, that would be a useful to know as a viable workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just *split* by the `,` and then by `=`:

```
>>> result = ('CN=SERVER1,OU=General Servers,OU=Servers,OU=Computers,OU=Group,DC=Domain,DC=com', {})
>>> result[0].split(",")[0].split("=")[1]
'SERVER1'
```

This would work if `CN` is always at the beginning of the `dn` string.

Another option, that would work for any position of the `CN`, would be to *create a dictionary* from the key value pairs in the `dn`:

```
>>> d = dict(item.split("=") for item in result[0].split(","))
>>> d['CN']
'SERVER1'
```

Answer (score 0):

So, all in one `list comprehension`, assuming your result list is called l,

```
hosts = [row[0].split(",")[0].replace("CN=","") for row in l]
```

Some people would (fairly) complain that this is too confusing for a list comprehension, so you could split it into its parts, instead.

EDIT:

I was curious to see if there was a substantial difference between using str.replace() as I did and alecxe's method of using a second split. I made the list contain 5 million entries and ran them both. (I did convert Alecxe's version to a list comprehension). There was no significant time difference. So, pick your poison :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, for the record it worked. I just found the answer by alecxe slightly easier to implement in my situation so marked that as the right answer.